# Why is this use of parallel omp for in Rcpp causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I'd like to create a faster version of `x == x1 & y %in% Table`, possibly compounded with other logical expressions. However, I can reliably produce a segfault when I run the following

```cpp
#include <omp.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


bool do_is_in(int x, IntegerVector Table, int tn) {
  for (int i = 0; i < tn; ++i) {
    if (x == Table[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector in_and_eq(IntegerVector x, int x1,
                        IntegerVector y, IntegerVector Table) {
  R_xlen_t n = x.length();

  LogicalVector out = no_init(n);
  const int tn = Table.length();

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    out[i] =
      x[i] == x1 &&
      do_is_in(y[i], Table, tn);
  }

  return out;
}
```

```r
i <- rep_len(1:17, 100e3)
j <- rep_len(1:19, 100e3)

in_and_eq(i, 15L, j, 15:18)  # may require a few repetitions
```

I suspect that it's something to do with `const int tn` but I'm not sure if that's a red herring. I've included it to avoid the (probably tiny) overhead of calling `Table.length()` for each `do_is_in` call.

Comment: It is all explained _e.g._ in the decent RcppParallel documentation: you cannot (re-)use R-allocated memory as a `gc()` event may take place.  Hence the use of `RVector` and `RMatrix` in that package. Maybe study the examples there?

Answer (score -1):

R is absolutely 100% not multi-threading safe. For example, your call to do_is_in takes in an object of type IntegerVector by value. This will call a copy constructor, which (I assume) will interact with R from a thread which is not thread 0, and therefore crash.

One way to do this is to reduce everything to raw pointers, or non-R data-types, and then you can use OpenMP just fine. E.g. your function signature becomes `bool do_is_in(int x, int* Table, int tn)`.

There may be a proper way to accomplish this built into Rcpp, but I'v never tried to go that route.

Comment: Not correct as stated. The raw pointer doesn't buy anything _as long as it still points to the same memory chunk from R_ which is precisely what you get via Rcpp and its "no copy" semantices.  Here you need actual copies.